Concatenate multiple string values into one value
I have usually 10, but up to 99, string values that are max 5 char long and separated by spaces.
I want to concat them into one field so I can report them across the page with word-wrap managing the really long values.
How to do this? I don’t know the no. of values until the data is returned.
Dataset
Num Qty Value
1   2   456
1   2   457
2   8   837
2   8   838
2   8   839
2   8   840
2   8   841
2   8   842
2   8   843
2   8   844
3   3   901
3   3   902
3   3   903

Desired output
Num Qty Values
1   2   456  457
2   8   837  838  839  840  841  842  843  844
3   3   901  902  903

Data details

What is this question about? More specific, what language?

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
